# Selecting only one button at a time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have just placed 4 UIButtons on a view, when i run the app it is possible to select many buttons at time( all are in highlighted state). Even though selector will be called on only one button. In general how to avoid multiple selection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the UIView-property `exclusiveTouch` to `YES` for each `UIButton`.